How to approach publications when my information source isn't published?
I recently posted a mathematical question on MSE. I got a very useful, non-trivial answer that completes the last piece of information i needed to produce an article. By now, i haven't found any source that contains the said information, and it is likely that the user provided the answer by solving himself the problem i posted. This, of course was a good thing, but now I can't state I am the sole author of the whole article, because not all the important content came from myself or published information... Also, i am unable to contact this user in any way, as he isn't answering my comments on MSE. I am pretty sure I can backtrack his solution and pretend I came up with it, but i wouldn't like to do that... and i'm not even sure if it could be considered plagiarism.
What should I do in this situation? I'm  still waiting for a response, but I'd like to think about my alternatives.

You have to cite ideas you use, wherever you find them. It's not like things don't "count" if they aren't in a specific type of venue. If someone tells you a solution on the bus ride to campus, even if you don't remember their name you should at least cite the anonymous bus conversation. And if it's on Stack Exchange, it is published in some sense.

See also https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/402/in-writing-a-research-paper-how-can-i-refer-to-peoples-answers-given-to-a-ques
